# Perl problems printing nested loop output after Parallelizing

Tags: perl

I'm trying to print output of [the following code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26129684/1733163), but there is something wrong with it, some lines do not have 5 columns, some values are missing, mixed , ....

./script.pl file 5 0.00 0.021

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Parallel::ForkManager;

my $outputfilename = $ARGV[0];
my $CPU_count      = $ARGV[1];
my $start          = $ARGV[2];
my $end            = $ARGV[3];


my $fork_manager = Parallel::ForkManager->new($CPU_count);

for ( my $k1 = $start; $k1 < $end; $k1 += 0.001 ) {

    $fork_manager->start and next;

    for ( my $k2 = $start; $k2 < $end; $k2 += 0.01 ) {
        for ( my $k3 = $start; $k3 < $end; $k3 += 0.001 ) {
            for ( my $k4 = $start; $k4 < $end; $k4 += 0.001 ) {
                for ( my $k5 = $start; $k5 < $end; $k5 += 0.001 ) {

open my $F1, '>',$outputfilename . "_" . $k1 . $k2 . $k3 . $k4 . $k5  or die $!;
         print  $F1 ("k1: $k1\tk2: $k2\tk3: $k3\tk4: $k4\tk5: $k5\n");

                }
            }
        }
    }
    $fork_manager->finish;
}
$fork_manager->wait_all_children;
```

incorrect output

```
...
k1: 0.002   k2: 0.00    k3: 0.00    k4: 0.016   k5: 0.006
k1: 0.002   k00 k2: 0.00    k3: 0.001   k4: 0.012   k5: 0.003
k1: 0.003   k2: 0.00    k3: 0.012   k4: 0.013   k5: 0.001
k1: 0.003   k2: 0.00    k3: 0.012   0.011
....
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: `"k1: ",$k1,"\t","k2: ",$k2,"\t","k3: ",$k3,"\t","k4: ",$k4,"\t","k5: ",$k5,"\n"` better written `"k1: $k1\tk2: $k2\tk3: $k3\tk4: $k4\tk5: $k5\n"`

Comment: you're running multiple threads in parallel all outputting to the same stream at once - what did you think would happen?

Comment: @MarkReed you are correct, I also tried to separate them and write to different output but it was not successful :(

Comment: My comment came out flipper than I intended.  A better way of putting my question: what did you *want* to happen?  Do you want each one to write to a separate file, or ... ?

Comment: @MarkReed actually doesn't matter. If I write them to separate files at the end I will merge them.

Comment: Having each fork open '$k1.output' it'd create a bunch of output files, but they'd each be unique and you could collate. Otherwise you'll trip over the fundamental problem of parallel code - it's just a big bundle of race conditions.

Comment: @Sobrique great, works nicely :) I added, would you please have a look to see whether this is what you mean! it generates a lots of files.

Comment: Wouldn't do it that way - that's one file per iteration, which'll be expensive. I'd suggest just after the `$fork_manager->start` do the open there - create a file called `$k1.output` or similar - you'll get one per fork (so about 1000 files if doing 0..1) and so no race condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for ( my $k1 = $start; $k1 < $end; $k1 += 0.001 ) {

    $fork_manager->start and next;
    open ( my $output, ">", $outputfilename."_".$k1 ) or die $!;
    for ( my $k2 = $start; $k2 < $end; $k2 += 0.01 ) {
        for ( my $k3 = $start; $k3 < $end; $k3 += 0.001 ) {
            for ( my $k4 = $start; $k4 < $end; $k4 += 0.001 ) {
                for ( my $k5 = $start; $k5 < $end; $k5 += 0.001 ) {
                    print  {$output} ("k1: $k1\tk2: $k2\tk3: $k3\tk4: $k4\tk5: $k5\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    close ( $output );
    $fork_manager->finish;
}
$fork_manager->wait_all_children;


foreach ( my $filename, glob ( "$outputfilename_*" ) ) {
     #stick together the results of something. 
}
```

You'll end up with one file per fork - so from 0..1 you'll get 1000. But each fork will have one active output filehandle, so no race condition.

Answer (score 2):

Your forks are racing to write to file. Depending on what you want from your output, you should place exclusive file locks on strategic points.

In example below at least lines won't get mixed up.

```
 use Fcntl qw(:flock);

 # ...
 flock($F1, LOCK_EX) or die $!;
 print $F1 ("k1: ",$k1,"\t","k2: ",$k2,"\t","k3: ",$k3,"\t","k4: ",$k4,"\t","k5: ",$k5,"\n");
 flock($F1, LOCK_UN);
```

Comment: Note that it could make your forks as slow as serial processing.

Comment: @choroba it would be interesting to see benchmark how much flock version is slower than original one.

Comment: Still there some lines get mixed up! :(

Comment: @EpiMan try `$F1->autoflush` after `open ..`

Comment: @mpapec Tnx. I tried. using both flock and autoflush make it better but still some blank and some double (2 times five columns in a row) and flock make the process slower. However, without flock the output as a mess!!

Comment: If you 'flock' then your processes will slow, because they're bound by the IO rate to your disk. Autoflush is useful, but close will also force a flush. But either way - each of your processes will be contending for a single file, so slow down dramatically.